# Hall's theorem using Konig Egervary max min theorem for matrices.

Tags: combinatorics

Using Konig Egervary theorem for m x n matrices, how can I deduce Hall's theorem? My book says that it's actually bidirectional but I only have to show that Konig theorem implies Hall's theorem. I don't know any graph theory other than our brief discussion of bipartite graphs.

The hint says to construct a matrix with entries "0" if the ith element is in the jth set, and 1 otherwise.

Comment: The König–Egerváry theorem (and Hall's theorem) are usually stated as theorems about perfect matchings in bipartite graphs. To make sure no confusion occurs, could you give their statements as you're using them for $m\times n$ matrices and elements of sets?

Comment: The Wikipedia article [on Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) may be helpful in avoiding the confusion noted by @MishaLavrov, and perhaps in giving you some ideas to connect the matrix and bipartite graph matching constructions.